# How to add more values into a declared variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to insert a values into a declared variable.
This is how it is so far :

```
INSERT INTO DP_Transaction(Trans_Reference, Trans_Action, Trans_Name,
Trans_Date, Trans_Comment) 
VALUES(@formId, 'Cancelled by', 'Workflow Manager', '2021-03-29 09:52:28.257', 'test')
```

And the values I want to add inside @formid is something like below:

```
'12323985',
'39864345',
'89426596',
'97070302',
'56746838'
```

And my expected result is all the values inside the statement will be insert into these @formId rows:
'12323985',
'39864345',
'89426596',
'97070302',
'56746838'

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your expect result could you give us more detial?

Comment: hi @D-Shih I have updated my questions. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could place the form ID values into a subquery and then rephrase the insert as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO DP_Transaction (Trans_Reference, Trans_Action,
    Trans_Name, Trans_Date, Trans_Comment)
SELECT
    formid,
    'Cancelled by',
    'Workflow Manager',
    '2021-03-29 09:52:28.257',
    'test'
FROM
(
    SELECT '12323985' AS formid UNION ALL
    SELECT '39864345' UNION ALL
    SELECT '89426596' UNION ALL
    SELECT '97070302' UNION ALL
    SELECT '56746838'
) t;
```

If you were using a different database, e.g. SQL Server, then you could have used `APPLY` along with a string splitting function.  But this is not an option in MySQL to my knowledge.